# Is it allowable to transfer from one terminal to another just for night stay?

Tags: layovers, cdg

It seems some of the terminals have good sleeping area in Paris CDG airport. My arrival and departure terminals may be different. Will I be allowed to go to a terminal where I want to spend my layover in as I wish? Or do I have to stick to my departure terminal?

Comment: I think you need to pass security every time you move between terminals and I am not sure whether you can do that without the relevant boarding pass. I would guess no because no airport allows that.

Comment: @chx OP can always buy a throwaway/refundable ticket to pull it off

Comment: @JonathanReez Are tickets (even full fare flexible ones) refundable after check-in? I always thought the whole point of check-in was sorting out who was actually flying or not.

Comment: @Relaxed Air France checks you in automatically, under certain conditions: http://www.airfrance.fr/FR/en/common/guidevoyageur/e_services/e_services_enregistrement_automatique_airfrance.htm. You can also buy a regular fare from a low-cost career and then simply choose not to fly.

Comment: @JonathanReez Okay but does that mean it's still refundable?

Comment: @Relaxed If it was fully refundable in the first place, then it should be refundable after check-in as well. AFAIK the deadline is at the moment when you enter the plane.

Comment: @JonathanReez It's been my question all along, do you know that for a fact? It seems a little counter-intuitive. Since you mentioned Air France, I just looked up their website and the [section on refunds](http://www.airfrance.fr/FR/fr/local/avotreservice/relationclientele/airfrance_remboursement.htm) explicitly states you cannot get your money back if you have a boarding pass.

Comment: But the same site also suggests that it is possible to cancel a check-in until the end of the check-in time. So it's clear the deadline isn't the moment you enter the plane but your plan might still be workable, at least if using the boarding pass to enter the terminal doesn't preclude cancelling the check-in. It would also require carefully selecting the flight so that the times more-or-less match (it's not like a fake flight out of the country). How long in advance is it possible to enter the terminal?

Comment: @Relaxed in any case I see a few flights from CDG priced at $50, which might be a reasonable fee for a traveler, although at that point it's probably cheaper to use a hotel outside the secure zone

Comment: @Relaxed this could be a great separate question by the way!

Answer (score 2):

When changing terminals at CDG, you would have to go through either a security check or passport control, or both.  [EasyCDG](http://easycdg.com/passenger-information/connecting-flight-connections-paris-cdg-airport/where-to-go/) has a tool that guides you, and gives step-by-step directions.

[You can identify your arrival and departure terminals](http://easycdg.com/airport-guide/which-terminal-paris-cdg-airport-charlesdegaulle/).  You can stay in the secure area of either of those terminals. If the area you want is in another terminal's secure area, you wouldn't be able to enter without having the correct boarding pass.